# Access Denied with Login CDN

Tags: authentication-authorization

I'm using Drupal with CloudFront CND. Drupal works very well without CloudFront, but I get an error when I try to login in my website after enable CloudFront, the user is ok, the pass is ok but I get 'Access Denied".

This happen always when I enable CloudFront. Also, If I change my host file and I set my server's ip pointing to my address I can get access.

I was thinking that it could be a problem with CloudFront and I check if my CloudFront allow POST method (it allows all). After that I check the CDN options and I think that maybe I can set some type of whitlist to avoid to get my website from CloudFront, for expample, if I go to the url "www.mywebsite.com/login", it would be served from the server and not from CloudFront.

I check if I can do it added to this option: DRUPAL PATH FOR AUTHENTICATED USERS, but it doesnt works adding "admin*" or "user*", I use /user to login and admin the website.

Someone can help me?

Comment: _If I change my host file and I set my server's ip pointing to my address I can get access._ so your problem is that DNS hasn't propagated yet, right? Nothing Drupal can do to help you with that, no. You have to wait like we all do for such things

Comment: I have a week with this problem... I'm starting to think that maybe could be a cookie problem, but I don't find where it is.

Comment: If it works when you provide a static DNS record, then the problem is likely to be DNS further up the chain. Try setting you DNS to google's to at least eliminate

Comment: I was checking today, I'm pretty sure that is a problem of a cookie domain. I mean, I have 2 domains, cloudfront.net and midomain.com. 
I would like to disable the cookie_domain or something like that but I think I cant do that.

Comment: If you're serving content from 2 different hosts then yeah, that'd do it. 2 different domains can't share the same cookie, It's a security feature that all major browsers adhere to strictly (for good reason)

Comment: Yes, I undertand that, buy my problem is that one URL is from CloudFront and the other one is my server (or something like that). When I send the login form I do it from cloudfront and (I think) when the post arrives to the destiny, it do it in my server... 
Im getting crazy with this error. I had tried to change the cookie_domain and put it cloudfront.net, .*... etc I understand the security feature but I must be forgoting something to configure welll the CDN.

Comment: You need to work out the _or something like that_ part. Otherwise you're just asking people to guess a solution based on no information, which they won't be able to do

Comment: I need ideas, I don't understand why I cant login to Drupal with CloudFront, if is a cookie problem (I guess this is the problem) I would like to know what I need to change in the Drupal configuration to be able to login on my site with CloudFront.

Comment: Are you accessing your site over the cloudfront domain or your own? If it's cloudfront then the issue could easily be cookie related. Sometimes people create a separate "edit" host name which avoids the CDN to avoid issues like this.